How to start tree of applications with dependencies
I need to be able to automatically start a requested application.
Every application can have pre requisite applications that need to be started before it starts, and an application can itself be a pre-requisite for a 'higher level' application.
Application startup can be complex enough that each application requires a startup script to get it going.
I need to be able to start some selected application, which means first making sure its dependencies are started, and if necessary their dependencies and so on.
I also need to be able to stop an application, which means first stopping the things that depend on it.
I was thinking of defining the pre requisites in a file, and writing a python script that worked out what to start in which order.
I need to be able to do this on Linux and Windows.
Is there a better or simpler approach?

How are your applications packaged and deployed?

A mix of vendor products and home grown apps.

how are they deployed? are these apps deployed as containers/plain binaries/services or something else?


how are they deployed? are these apps deployed as containers/plain binaries/services or something else?
All of the above :)



I need to be able to start some selected application, which means first making sure its dependencies are started, and if necessary their dependencies and so on.

this is already implemented in almost all modern Linux distros: Service managers that have an understanding of the dependencies a service declares, and start (and stop) them in the appropriate order.
The most relevant of these managers, which almost all distros use (and the ones that don't usually figure out their own ways to make your declaration for them) is systemd. You just go, and write a "systemd service file", which is honestly just an INI file that says "hey, my service is called XYZ, here's how you start it, and how you stop it, and here's the things it depends on".
That's it. Then you just tell systemd to please start that to reach the default "system is up and running" state.
If your software consists of multiple, mutually dependent services, you write such a service file for each. Don't worry, they are typically less than 15 lines each.
Services can be started by the system during boot, or by individual users for their sessions.

I was thinking of defining the pre requisites in a file, and writing a python script that worked out what to start in which order.

Don't. This is already solved for you, see above. And you're underestimating the complexity of the problem if you forget that you need to know a way to tell whether a dependency service is still starting or already fully operation, that you also need proper shutdown ordering, and a controlled way to deal with failures (restart service automatically? Just mark system as broken? Shut down dependents?), and some way to make things "monitorable".
It's all already solved; don't reinvent the wheel.
(Systemd brings a lot more really handy features for service design, like the option of activating a service only when something tries to connect to a socket, or central log management, or optional resource limitation, or temporary directory handling, and a lot more things)

I need to be able to do this on Linux and Windows.

Windows services are so fundamentally different that the same logic can't apply to both platforms, so you will need to figure that out for Windows separately. Your python approach wouldn't be good on Windows, either, you should still do proper services. I'm afraid for Windows service design, you'll have to ask in a different place – specifically not the platform we are knowledgable around here.
